# How to call a site's function from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extention for myself, so that when I visit any sort of channel at [Twitch.tv](http://www.twitch.tv), the chat will automatically hide.

I've been looking at it with Firebug and I found `toggle_chat()`. If I type that in the console, the chat is no longer visible.

In my userscript file, I have written

```
window.onload = function() {
toggle_chat();
}
```

but it says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_chat is not defined" in the console when I load a Twitch channel.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: most likely you're calling it too soon. Good luck finding out when to call the method.

Comment: I agree with the above I would play around with the console a bit more and see what you can make happen

Comment: I tried making it wait for 10 seconds before executing, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is very hacky, but it gets the job done, and sometimes that exactly what you need. :) It'll check for the function roughly ever half second until it exists. When it's finally there, it'll call the function then clear the timer.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var id = null;

    var check = function() {
        if (typeof toggle_chat === "function") {
            toggle_chat();
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }

    id = setInterval(check, 500);
}
```

Comment: This also worked out really well. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with timing. Chrome extensions and content scripts execute in an [`isolated world`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment), meaning they have no access to the page's javascript including functions. You could make it so that your `content script` appends a `<script>` element that then calls the page function that you want but it would be far easier to just simulate a click on the `#right_close` element. You can do this with pure Javascript like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
  evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);
  document.querySelector('#right_close').dispatchEvent(evObj);
}
```